# Progress bar with custom background multiple color css/jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, progress-bar

my target is realize a progress bar with custom background.
the final result should be look at this:

[image]

the background it's (in order) green, yellow and red.
The lightblue color it's over the background...the progress line.

There are some tutorial for make this?
I've already realize some progress bar, but nothing with custom background that i would.
Thanks.

Comment: If you require help with existing code you've created, please add that code to the question. Questions asking for plugin recommendations are off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply use linear-gradient and you can specify as many color as you want and control the % of each one easily:

```css
.progress {
 height:52px;
 width:500px;
 border:2px solid #000;
 text-align:center;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:20px;
 background:linear-gradient(to right, red 20%, blue 20%, blue 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 60% ,green 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress"> 50 %</div>
```

You can also consider multiple gradient and you can easily manage them using jQuery by adjusting `background-size`:

```css
.progress {
 height:52px;
 width:500px;
 border:2px solid #000;
 text-align:center;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:20px;
 background-image:
   linear-gradient(red,red),
   linear-gradient(blue,blue),
   linear-gradient(green,green),
   linear-gradient(yellow,yellow);
 background-size:
   4% 100%,
   50% 100%,
   60% 100%,
   100% 100%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 transition:1s;
}
.progress:hover {
 background-size:
   20% 100%,
   30% 100%,
   90% 100%,
   100% 100%;
}
```

```html
Hover to see the animation !
<div class="progress"> 50 %</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Gradients below is the sample code.I have try

```css
/* PROGRESS */
.progress {
  background-color: #e5e9eb;
  height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  width: 34em;
}
.progress-bar {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: width;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #4cd964, #5ac8fa, #007aff, #34aadc, #5856d6, #ff2d55);
  background-size: 24em 0.25em;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
@keyframes width {
  0%, 100% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.65, 0.85);
  }
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
  <h1 class="text-center">Progress Bar</h1>

  <div class="progress">

    <div class="progress-bar">

      <div class="progress-shadow"></div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: `progress-shadow` is for what ? by the way you can rely on only one element and animate the background-size to animate the gradient, no need to have 2 element ;)

Comment: background-size and background-image made my day, both together are all what I needed in order to conserve the absolute relation between colors regarding the width, thank you...

Answer (score 4):

You can create a stacked progress bar by placing multiple bars into the same div with class .progress as shown in this [w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Stacked Progress Bars</h2>

  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:40%">
      Free Space
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" style="width:10%">
      Warning
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">
      Danger
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are willing to use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) in your project, just use its [Progress bar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/) component.

Even if you don't want to use Bootstrap (or similar frameworks), take a look at that as an example to build yours.

Comment: Sorry but where you see the custom background with different color in your example link?