# Stacked progress bar appearing in same colour when I want different ones

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want a stacked progress bar with different colours. Like the one shown here in "multiple bars" here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/

I have tried various types of code and all of them provide a stacked progress bar but all of the colours remain blue, so it does not appear as a stacked progress bar. I provide one attempt below:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 15%" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

There are no error messages, just instead of having 3 different colours as expected, I just get blue.

Is the following css not sufficient?:
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Any help greatly appreciated for a beginner :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress bar with custom background multiple color css/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48704339/progress-bar-with-custom-background-multiple-color-css-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">` because your using bootstrap 4 not 3

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 15%" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is `Bootstrap 4` but you are using `bootstrap 3.4.0`

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/5b74shqc/3/

Answer (score 0):

it seems working fine please update your css and js with latest.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 15%" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your Boot strap link file with
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />